# Is there a way to get the vertices array from a three.js QuickHull instance?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm trying to create a geometry from a quickhull of a THREE Mesh, but the QuickHull instance only appears to have information relevant to the Faces.

Is there a way to get each vertex information from this instance?

Thank you in advance.

```
const hull = new QuickHull().setFromObject(mesh) //Mesh is an already rendered object
//hull.vertices //this returns the entire geometry instead of the hull's vertices
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible. Try it like so:

```
const hull = new THREE.QuickHull().setFromObject( mesh );
const vertices = [];

const faces = quickHull.faces;

for ( let i = 0; i < faces.length; i ++ ) {

    const face = faces[ i ];
    let edge = face.edge;

    do {

        const point = edge.head().point;

        vertices.push( point.x, point.y, point.z );

        edge = edge.next;

    } while ( edge !== face.edge );

}
```

As you can see, the idea is to use the half-edges of the faces in order collect all vertices in the correct order.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much.